# Simple shell script not working

Tags: linux, shell

I am trying to run a simple shell script. This is the code that I have written.

```
INPUT = "."
OUTPUT = "."

cp "$INPUT/file.txt" "$OUTPUT/new_test.txt"
```

**Error:** I am getting the following error.

```
INPUT command not found
OUTPUT command not found
```

**Problem:** What am I doing wrong? And how can I run modify it to run it successfully? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the blanks arround the equals sign:

```
INPUT="."
OUTPUT="."
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the blanks around the `=`. The shell delimits tokens by space (and other token delimiters, like `&`, ...) Thus, `INPUT = "."` is interpreted as calling the command `INPUT` with two arguments, `=` and `.`.